# How do I put the output of SHAPE() into two variables?

Tags: fortran

How do I put the output of `SHAPE()` into two variables?

Consider the case I generate an array like this:

```
  REAL :: r(1,10)
  CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(r)
```

how do I put the dimensions `1` and `10` into two variables `l1` and `l2`?

Comment: Are you referring to array size? If so `l1 = size(r,DIM=1)` and `l2 = size(r,DIM=2)`.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Fortran 2018 Standard](https://j3-fortran.org/doc/year/18/18-007r1.pdf)

> **16.9.179 `SIZE (ARRAY [, DIM, KIND])`:**
>
> *1. Description:* Size of an array or one extent.
> *5. Result Value:* If `DIM` is present, the result has a value equal to the extent of dimension `DIM` of `ARRAY`, except that if `ARRAY` is assumed-rank and associated with an assumed-size array and DIM is present with a value equal to the rank of `ARRAY`, the value is −1. If `DIM` is absent and `ARRAY` is assumed-rank, the result has a value equal to `PRODUCT(SHAPE(ARRAY, KIND))`. Otherwise, the result has a value equal to the total number of elements of `ARRAY`.

So I would do:

```
l1 = size(array,dim=1)
l2 = size(array,dim=2)
```

Also [see comment from @jcerar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60077545/how-do-i-put-the-output-of-shape-into-two-variables#comment106254324_60077545)

Another way of doing it is by using `SHAPE`:

> **16.9.172 `SHAPE (SOURCE [, KIND])`:**
>
> *1. Description:* Shape of an array or a scalar.
> *5. Result Value:* The result has a value whose ith element is equal to the extent of dimension `i` of `SOURCE`, except that if `SOURCE` is assumed-rank, and associated with an assumed-size array, the last element is equal to `−1`.

```
integer, dimension(:), allocatable :: l
l = shape(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answeer myself after some experimenting.

One has to define an array

```
integer,dimension(0:1)::s1
```

and the just use `s1=shape(r)`

Comment: Do you mean `dimension(0:1)` rather than `dimension(0,1)`?  That first would be correct (if not necessarily the best idea).

Comment: @francescalus thanks that was a typo. Thanks for pointing it out. What would be the best idea?

Comment: @mattiav27 Starting at 1 is pretty common... dimension(2) implies s1(1:2)